# Java Serialization empty file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I have some java serialization code. It compiles and ran properly. But the resultant file is empty. Below is my code

The parameters are either arraylist of integers, arraylist of Strings or arraylist of arraylists of integers

```
Model model = new Model(
    pennTreeTags,
    tagsCount,
    iOccurTable,
    fOccurTable,
    alVocab,
    aiVocabCount,
    wordTagTable,
    fWordTagProb
);

try 
{
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(argv[2]);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    model = (Model) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
}
catch (EOFException ex) 
{ 
    //This exception will be caught when EOF is reached
    System.out.println("End of file reached.");
}
catch(IOException i)
{
    i.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
{
    System.out.println("Model class not found");
    c.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you posted the wrong code?  There's no serialisation occurring here - this looks like de-serialisation from file?

Comment: Did you just decide to lock yourself in a room with no Internet access and no java docs or books to refer to when you wrote this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing anything to any file. You are only reading from a file.
If you want to write to a file use an *Output*Stream.

Comment: HAHA yes I just realised....no wonder my file is empty, Thanks!